# grep: start matching line at given position (skip first n characters)

Tags: shell, grep, regular-expression

I have file containing lines in following format:

```
2021-Jan-26 05:35  foo bar 2
2021-Jan-26 05:37  asdf 2 foo bar
2021-Jan-26 05:37  foo
```

The patterns that I am interested start at position 20. So when I grep the file for specific pattern, I want to skip (not match) first 19 characters.

So, I want to match a pattern anywhere on the line, except first 19 characters

In the example above, if I grep for `2`, I only want to match lines 1 and 2.

How can I do this with `grep` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option using GNU `grep`, that will ignore the first 19 characters and match only the pattern you need:

```
grep -P "(?<=.{19})2" file
```

Output:

```
2021-Jan-26 05:35  foo bar 2
2021-Jan-26 05:37  asdf 2 foo bar
```

Comment: it does not work as expected. When I use `bar` as pattern, it matches any of the characters `a`, `b`, `r`: `grep -P "(?<=.{19})[bar]+"`

Comment: @400theCat You have to adjust the regex according to the pattern you need. My answer reflected what you gave as example. For "bar" matching: `grep -P "(?<=.{19})bar"`.

Comment: @400theCat maybe I didn't need the `[2]+`, updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You actually do want to match the first 19, but match them to "anything".

So

```
grep '^....................*2'
```

There are 20 dots. The `^` anchors the pattern to the start of the line. The next 19 dots match one character each, in effect skipping over them. Then come `.*` which matches zero or more character, then comes `2` to match the pattern you want.

You can make this potentially more efficient with

```
grep '^..................[^2]*2'
```

which matches start of line, then 19 characters, then zero or more characters which are not `2` then a `2`. There will not be any significant difference in this case but if the pattern being searched for is more elaborate then this optimization may help a lot.

Comment: that works. The only problem is that grep now color highlights the whole line up to my matching pattern, not just the pattern itself.

Comment: Or `grep '^.\{19\}.*2'` or `grep -E '^.{19}.*2'`.