# grep (or sed?): skip a specified number of lines before looking for matches

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I'm working with huge log files that accumulate over days that I can't truncate/rotate but need to parse new entries hourly.

I've been using `grep` to grab entries with a specific string then counting how many I get and tossing the first `N`, where `N` is the number of entries

I've already ingested on all prior loops, but of course this means inefficiently grepping the whole file every loop. I'm relatively unix naive, but I feel like there's a more efficient way to do this? I don't think `tail` would work because I won't know how many new lines have been written since the last parsing. [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178460/grep-skip-n-lines-of-file-and-only-search-after) talks of skipping, but using a search string to determine how many lines to skip whereas I'd be looking to supply the skip number as an argument. [This one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631019/grep-start-matching-line-at-given-position-skip-first-n-characters) speaks to skipping a specified number of characters on each line, but I'd be looking to skip a specified number of lines.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out while writing the Q, posting for posterity:

```
tail -n+N file | grep ...
```

where N is the number of lines to skip minus 1.

Comment: Or `tail -f -n+M file | grep ...` to carry on searching afterwards waiting for more lines to be added.

Comment: Or `sed '/start pattern/,$!d; /pattern/!d'` to look for `pattern` starting with the first line that matches `pattern`.

Comment: Or `awk '$0 >= "2021-06-14 10:00" && /pattern/'` if your logs are timestamped like that.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` can be used to skip an initial number of lines.  The command

```bsh
sed '1,200d'
```

would delete the first 200 lines and pass all other lines on unchanged.

Likewise, `awk` could be used in a similar manner:

```bsh
awk 'FNR > 200'
```

The above command would print line 201 and on but discard earlier lines.  The `FNR` variable is the number of records (lines by default) read from the current file.

You could parametrize this easily to take a number from the command line:

```bsh
awk -v n=200 'FNR > n'
```

You could also combine it with `grep` (replacing the function of `grep` with `awk`):

```bsh
awk -v n=200 'FNR > n && /pattern/' somefile
```

... where `pattern` is some extended regular expression.

Or, to take the pattern from some value on the command line,

```bsh
awk -v n=200 -v p='pattern' 'FNR > n && $0 ~ p'
```

or, safer, using an environment variable,

```bsh
pattern='pattern' awk -v n=200 'FNR > n && $0 ~ ENVIRON["pattern"]' somefile
```

Comment: Any comment on the relative efficiency of `tail -n+N file | grep …` vs your see & awk options?

Comment: @MikeLawrence No. This depends on the implementation of the tools and the characteristics of the system that is used. What may be faster on one person's system, may be slower on some other person's system. Benchmarking is best made individually.